# Select from multiple table with order by showing only one

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select user comments using group by and left join, I need to select multiple rows in each table so I select all (*).

But my both queries showing only one, I played with it in pm and always returning same result.

My comment table has 10 comments in it, and problem is not with pagination.

First example :

```
SELECT 
COUNT(comments.com_uid) AS com_total,
comments.comment_sender_name,
comments.com_status, 
comments.com_read, 
comments.comment, 
comments.comment_id, 
posts.post_id, 
posts.post_seo_url, 
posts.post_userId, 
users.user_id, 
users.username, 
users.slug
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN posts ON comments.com_uid = posts.post_userId
LEFT JOIN users ON comments.com_uid = users.user_id
WHERE comments.com_uid = ?
GROUP BY comments.comment_sender_name 
ORDER BY com_total 
DESC LIMIT $start, $limit
```

Second Example :

```
SELECT `cmt`.*, `ust`.*, `pst`.*, COUNT(`cmt`.`com_uid`) AS `com_total`
FROM `comments` AS `cmt`
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `ust` ON `cmt`.`com_uid` = `ust`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS `pst` ON `cmt`.`com_uid` = `pst`.`post_userId`
WHERE `cmt`.`com_uid` = `cmt`.`com_uid`
GROUP BY `cmt`.`com_uid` ORDER BY `com_total` DESC;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your group by makes little sense and you probably need to look at [mysql_only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Comment: @Stu when I try without group by then it displays two of each comments.

Comment: Let's start at the beginning. You say: _"But my both queries showing only one"_. Does this mean both queries only return one row, or does it mean `com_total` is one?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware They both return only 1 row, `com_total` should have 10 comments in it, as I said in question `My comment table has 10 comments in it`.

Comment: Sorry, I read it as: _"I get 1, but I have 10 comments."_. My mistake.

Comment: Well, you filter on the user id: `comments.com_uid = ?`, and you group by user name: `comments.comment_sender_name`. Both are probably the same user. So you only get one result row because you group by user and you only accept one user. If you want all 10 comments in separate rows, you shouldn't group by the user. The number of rows then can be used as the count of comments.